# Debian VPN pptp-linux not storing credentials

Tags: command-line, password, vpn, pptp

I'm using pptp-linux to connect to a PPTP VPN (served by a Windows Server).
Following some tutorials I configured the following files:

/etc/ppp/peers/VPN-Name

/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/route-traffic

/etc/ppp/chap-secrets

Then I start the vpn using "pon VPN-Name" and everything works fine.

Is it possible to make the connection without storing username/password into the chap-secrets files? Or is there another way for connecting to a PPTP VPN from command line that require password typing?

Of course I will type it every time, but I'm unable to find anything working. If I simply remove credentials from /etc/ppp/chap-secrets the connection hang up automatically without asking me anything.

Thanks